# Dynamic instantiations passing parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I've ran into a problem of generating object instances from different classes dynamically. So I have a server response returning an array of products, these products vary in type which will vary on the instantiation class to be used as well as the parameters being passed into the constructor.

In the example below I have a root `class Product` which is extended by `class Food` and `classFurniture` these extension classes vary in parameters which need to be inserted in their relative `constructors()`.

I'm using the product property `product.metaType` to hold the info on what `class` to use in instantiation.

```js
//root product class which all inherit from
class Product{
 constructor(price){
  this.price = price;
  this.quantity = null;
 } 
}
//food product class
class Food extends Product{
 constructor(price,exp){
  super(price);
  this.expiration = exp;
 } 
}
//furniture product class
class Furniture extends Product{
 constructor(price,dimensions){
  this.price = price; 
  this.dimensions = dimensions; 
 } 
}
class Chair extends Furniture{
 constructor(price,dimensions,type){
  super(price,dimensions);
  this.type = type;
 }
}
class Pizza extends Food{
 constructor(price,exp,type){
  super(price,exp);
  this.type = type;
 }
}
class Cookies extends Food{
 constructor(price,exp,type){
  super(price,exp);
  this.type = type;
 }
}
class IceCream extends Food{
 constructor(price,exp,type){
  super(price,exp);
  this.type = type;
 }
}
//init (iife)
(()=>{ 
 //list of products emulated from a server response
 var products:[
  {
   metaType: "Pizza",
   name: "digiorno",
   price: 20,
   type: "pepperoni",
   exp: new Date()
  },
  {
   metaType: "Chair",
   name: "Lazy Boy",
   price: 400,
      dimensions:{
      height: 4,
      width: 2,
     length: 6
      },
   type: "modern"
  },
  {
   metaType: "Cookies",
   name: "Mrs. Fields",
   price: 10,
   type: "chocolate chip",
   exp: new Date()
  },
  {
   metaType: "IceCream",
   name: "Ben & Jerry's",
   price: 15,
   type: "half baked",
   exp: new Date()
  }
 ]; 
 var storeProducts = [];
 //loop through products array
 products.forEach((item)=>{
  //create new instance of the specific product, append to the 'storeProducts' array
  //each product contains a metaType property which is the CLASS to use
        //how can I dynamically do this?
  storeProducts.push(new window[item.metaType]());
 });
})();
```

**Question:** How can I dynamically instantiate different classes and pass parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `name -> constructor` map. `class`es do not become properties of the global object:

```
const cls = {Food, Furniture, ...};
```

Make the constructors accept a single argument and destructure it, e.g.

```
class Food extends Product{
  constructor({price,exp}){
      //      ^         ^    destructuring
      super(price);
      this.expiration = exp;
  } 
}
```

Then you can pass the whole object to the constructor:

```
 new cls[item.metaType](item);
```

Comment: You simple pass `item` to the constructor.

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't get what you were saying at first... just destructure in each class using `item`

Comment: is this the most efficient method you've seen? I was using `switch` statement before and was like how can I do it dynamically.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. `switch` works too of course. I can't imagine that this part is performance critical in your application.

Comment: I mean were talking milliseconds but they add up with a huge list, but were implementing pagination anyway, just always striving for the best I guess lol.